# Azure - SQL (IaaS or PaaS)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I've been trying to figure out if I can run my DBs using PaaS for a specific application.

The bit I can't quite find an answer to is if Azure DBs on PaaS supports running as a Transactional Publisher?

I've seen an article that says a DB in Azure is capable of being a subscriber, but can't find anything regarding the other way round.

Comment: I think that for this specific requirement, you should use IaaS...also from my experience Azure Sql Databases are kind of slow(at least on my geo zone)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but to be clear, is it actually technically possible?

Comment: If you better describe the task you are trying to solve, we will be better able to help you. When you go PaaS maybe you no longer need the "traditional" way of thinking about replication. Azure SQL DB (i.s. PaaS) has out of the box Active-Geo-Replication feature. Which does automatic replication of your database to another Azure Region. The articles you refer are [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/transactional-replication-to-azure-sql-db/) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt589530.aspx)

Comment: I think DBA.SE would be a better fit VTC

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Astaykov. I didn't explain in detail the requirements for the replication because I didn't feel it was necessary. However, the replication is not for redundancy of the database itself but for the application it serves, therefore GEO redundancy data centre services will not help. What I need to know is actually specifically what I have been asking, which to be honest i thought was a reasonable question and quite clear. Does Azure SQL PaaS allow for acting as a Transactionsl Publisher?

Answer (score 0):

Today SQL DB doesn't support transaction replication if the SQL DB database is the publisher.